# VSIXManifest cannot be loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-sdk, vsixmanifest

i've installed the Microsoft Visual Studio SDK to develop extensions for Visual Studio. But even when i create a simple example without any changes from the templates, Visual Studio refuses to fully compile the extension.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VSPackage1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  VSPackage1 -> 
1>  VSPackage1 -> 
1>  VSPackage1 -> o:\daten\visual studio 2012\Projects\VSPackage1\VSPackage1\bin\Debug\VSPackage1.dll
1>  Creating intermediate PkgDef file.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets(75,5): error : VSIXManifest cannot be loaded. Ensure VSIXManifest is a valid XML file.
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VSPackage1_IntegrationTests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  VSPackage1_IntegrationTests -> o:\daten\visual studio 2012\Projects\VSPackage1\VSPackage1\VSPackage1_IntegrationTests\bin\Debug\VSPackage1_IntegrationTests.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Projects build report:
  Status    | Project [Config|platform]
 -----------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Failed    | VSPackage1\VSPackage1.csproj [Debug|Any CPU]
  Succeeded | VSPackage1\VSPackage1_IntegrationTests\VSPackage1_IntegrationTests.csproj [Debug|Any CPU]

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.56
```

I did not change anything else. Any suggestions?

Comment: It says it cannot load the manifest. Shot in the dark: is there any chance of a permissions issue with that o:\ drive?